# Daterange split with individual start and end dates in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working in Python with Pandas, and need to divide a date range in multiple date ranges - and need both the start and end dates for these ranges

So something like:

```
pd.date_range(start='20180301', end='20180311',freq='3D')
```

should generate a list with two values per item:

```
[0] 20180301, 20180303
[1] 20180304, 20180306
[2] 20180307, 20180309
[3] 20180310, 20180311
```

(last period is shorter than 3 days but ends with the overall enddate)

Comment: can't you generate two separate lists ?

Comment: @Manish: That's definitely an option, but generating a list with startdate+1 will not work if you have date intervals like weeks, months etc.

Answer (score 6):

IIUC:

```
In [217]: dates = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start='20180301', end='20180311'))

In [218]: dates
Out[218]:
0    2018-03-01
1    2018-03-02
2    2018-03-03
3    2018-03-04
4    2018-03-05
5    2018-03-06
6    2018-03-07
7    2018-03-08
8    2018-03-09
9    2018-03-10
10   2018-03-11
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [219]: df = dates.groupby(np.arange(len(dates))//3).agg(['first', 'last'])

In [220]: df
Out[220]:
       first       last
0 2018-03-01 2018-03-03
1 2018-03-04 2018-03-06
2 2018-03-07 2018-03-09
3 2018-03-10 2018-03-11
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you want the format of your list to be, but as you're working in `pandas`, here is one option:

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='20180301', end='20180311',freq='3D')

df = pd.DataFrame([[i, x] for i, x in 
                   zip(dates, dates.shift(1)-pd.offsets.Day(1)], 
                   columns=['start','end'])

df['end'].iloc[-1] = dates[-1]+pd.offsets.Day(1)

>>> df
       start        end
0 2018-03-01 2018-03-03
1 2018-03-04 2018-03-06
2 2018-03-07 2018-03-09
3 2018-03-10 2018-03-11
```

The only unfortunate thing there is that you have to explicitly set the last `end` date to the end of your original date range (as I did with `df['end'].iloc[-1]`), but I can't really see any way around that.

Comment: I think your solution better cares of OP's needs ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I actually modified it to use `pd.offsets.Day(1)`, inspired by your post, so that it doesn't need to import `datetime`.

Comment: Nice solution! However, if I change the timefrequency to another range (like 1 week) it still has some issues regarding the end-date, but this might be avoided by comparing the enddate with the last 'end' date

Comment: True, the end date will be a bit weird, I can't really think of an elegant way to deal with it TBH

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same without using Pandas.

```
import datetime

firstDate = datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
lastDate = datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-03-30", "%Y-%m-%d")
numberOfDays = 15
startdate = firstDate
startdatelist = []
enddatelist = []

while startdate <= lastDate:
    enddate = startdate + datetime.timedelta(days=numberOfDays - 1)
    startdatelist.append(startdate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00"))
    if enddate > lastDate: enddatelist.append(lastDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59"))
    enddatelist.append(enddate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59"))
    startdate = enddate + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

for a, b in zip(startdatelist, enddatelist):
    print(str(a) + "  -  " + str(b))
```